# Aligning function statements on separate lines within 1 enumerated problem (how to)

Tags: align, amsmath, multicol, enumitem

Using these packages to create a 2 column, enumerated math worksheet: `amsmath`, `multicol` and `item`.

Within problems #9 and #10, I need to left align 3 items on separate lines as shown below:

[image: f(t) = 3t-1 g(t) = t^3 + t^2 Find (f - g)(t)]

I tried the `\align*` command and using `&` without effect.

Thanks very much for your assistance.

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{bm}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Math 111: Review}
{}
{} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
 }
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},    column-sep=2em,    
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\SolutionSpace}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{5cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
\definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{0.8}}% solutions are printed
{\setlength{\SolutionSpace}{0cm}
    \colorsolutionboxes 
    \definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{gray}{1}}% solutions are not being printed

\begin{document}
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Solve each equation.}}
\bigskip
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Perform the indicated operation.}}%
%%% Prob #9
\task 
$f(t)=3t-1$ \\
$g(t)=t^3+t^2$\\
Find $(f-g)(t)$\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
$(f-g)(t)=f(t)-g(t)$\bigskip
$(3t-1)-(t^3+t^2)=$
\colorbox{yellow}{$-t^3-t^2+3t-1$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%%% Prob #10
\task 
$f(x)=-2x^3-3x^2$ \\
$g(x)=x+1$ \\
Find $(f \cdot g)(x)$\bigskip
\begin{solutionorbox}[\SolutionSpace]
$(-2x^3-3x^2)(x+1)$\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$=-2x^4-5x^3-3x^2$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `aligned` instead. `$\begin{aligned}[t]
    f(t)&=3t-1 \\
g(t)&=t^3+t^2
\end{aligned}$\\Find $(f-g)(t)$`

Comment: @Sigur Thanks so much for the quick response! I copied your code. Worked perfectly except the "Find" statement didn't align with the 2 functions above. However, from a readability perspective, what do you think of this mod from the original layout (i.e. inserting ``\bigskip`` before "Find"? https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Whj.png

Comment: If you change the align point to the beginning,  you can move Find into it and use `&f ... \\ &g .... \\ &\text{Find } ... `